# Writing a long math expression

Tags: r

I am trying to write a long math equation, that goes as following:

> 1/x+1[(x^2 + 4x +1 / x^2 - 1)* log(x + sqrt(x^2 - 1)) - (x +3) / sqrt(x^2 -1)]

I've tried to define this in a function in R studio as following:

```
pho_ann <- function(x) {(1/(x+1))*((x^2)+4x)}
```

I haven't even able to write the full function and I am already getting errors:

> Error: unexpected symbol in "pho_ann <- function(x) {(1/(x+1))*((x^2)+4x"

what could be the source of error here? What can I do to write the whole expression?

Comment: R doesn't really care about indents; you are free to pad the functions with spaces and line breaks as generously as you want. It seems like the culprit in your case is the wrong number of closing brackets.

Comment: try `4*x` not `4x`

Comment: @user20650 haha I dont believe this. it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid errors

- change `4x` to `4*x`
- remove `1[` and `]`.

The function definition becomes:

```
pho_ann <- function(x){
    1/x + (x^2 + 4*x + 1/x^2 -1)* log(x + sqrt(x^2 - 1)) - (x + 3) / sqrt(x^2 - 1)
}
```

Comment: I would have imagined that `1[(` would throw an error but you say it's only unnecessary?

Comment: @42- You are right. I improved the wording.

Comment: Thank you! editing from 4x to 4*x did the magic. I should have specified that from 1[ , 1 is a placeholder for another integer variable.